# Can't create cluster in Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

So for my Lab I need to create a cluster in Dataproc.
I've followed all the steps listed so often I can do them blind now.

It just keeps coming up with an error saying I don't have permission.
I can't imagine I'm doing anything wrong.
Or could i...?

I'm on the third course from coursera Data Engineering

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Can you please copy paste the error to your question (you can edit it)? Do you see it in the Google Could console (the website) or in the `gcloud` command line?

Comment: @David van Aelst, have you followed all the steps in https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/create-cluster ?